# How to use pickadate.js

Tags: jquery

How to use Pickadate.js

My current setup to use pickadate.js
`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input").click(function(){

$("#inputdate").pickadate();  

});
</script>    `
```

But it is not displaying - I am new to jquery

Comment: You are missing `})`.

Comment: This is a good time to learn how the  [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) works.

Answer (score 4):

if you would indent the code correctly you would see it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input").click(function(){

            $("#inputdate").pickadate();  

        });
    }); //this was missing
</script>
```